# How high is highrep?

Tags: discussion, advertising, hyperlinks

The URL for the (non-opensource) ads contains the token `x-user-highrep`.

```
http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?Task=Click&ZoneID=4...&SiteID=1&RandomNumber=1390910444&Keywords=asp.net%2cencryption%2cx-user-highrep%2cx-user-registered
```

How much rep must one have to get that token?

On related notes:

- What other special tags are there?  (`x-user-mod`?)
- If the question itself has the `x-user-highrep` tag, it will be there for all users.  (I tried it)

Comment: I don't have x-user-highrep on serverfault (190 rep), but I do on stackoverflow (10.5k).. so it's somewhere between those two numbers.

Comment: How high? **So High**!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was that telerik ad that was only shown to 10k plus users a while back, so it could be that.

Comment: ding, winner! :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it might be the 200 rep (I think) that triggers the reduced advertising.

EDIT: No, it's not. See Jeff's comment.

Comment: if that was the case, it wouldn't be visible or served